# Using Material UI's Autocomplete using Formik to display different value in dropdown but set different value in formik state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I am trying to use Material UI's Autocomplete with Formik. Here is a custom Autocomplete component I wrote to use with Formik.

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { fieldToTextField } from "formik-material-ui";

const FormikAutocomplete = ({ textFieldProps, ...props }) => {
  const {
    form: { setTouched, setFieldValue },
  } = props;
  const { error, helperText, ...field } = fieldToTextField(props);
  const { name } = field;

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...props}
      {...field}
      onChange={(_, value) =>
        setFieldValue(name, value)
      }
      onBlur={() => setTouched({ [name]: true })}
      renderInput={(props) => (
        <TextField
          {...props}
          {...textFieldProps}
          helperText={helperText}
          error={error}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default FormikAutocomplete;
```

Here is how components callled

```
<Field
  name="title"
  component={FormikAutocomplete}
  options={gender}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title_name_long}
  textFieldProps={{
    label: "Title",
    required: true,
    variant: "outlined",
    margin: "dense",
  }}
/>
```

Now what I intend to do is: If I have a object like

```
gender=[{gender_name_short:"F",gender_name_long:"Female},{gender_name_short:"M",gender_name_long:"Male}]
```

I want the Autocomplete dropdown to show options male,female.
But I want the formik state to save M,F respectively once selected from dropdown. Currently the entire object gets saved.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `FormikAutocomplete` component,

- use setFieldValue in the onChange of autocomplete
- use `gender_name_long` in `getOptionLabel` to display `Male` , `Female`
- use `gender_name_short` in `getOptionSelected` to use `M` or `F`

With that, finally, when you submit, you will get to see `M`/`F` not `Male/Female`

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-material-ui-onsubmit-get-only-id-m00q8?file=/src/Component.tsx)

```js
const gender = [
  { gender_name_short: "F", gender_name_long: "Female" },
  { gender_name_short: "M", gender_name_long: "Male" }
];
const validationSchema = object().shape({
  // genderObj: array().required("At least one gender is required")
});

const initialValues = {
  username: "abc",
  country: "",
  gender: "M",
  birthdate: null
};

const FormikAutocomplete = ({ textFieldProps, ...props }) => {
  const {
    form: { setTouched, setFieldValue }
  } = props;
  const { error, helperText, ...field } = fieldToTextField(props);
  const { name } = field;

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      {...props}
      onChange={(_, data) => {
        setFieldValue("gender", data.gender_name_short);
      }}
      onBlur={() => setTouched({ [name]: true })}
      // getOptionLabel={item => item.gender_name_long} //<----see here
      getOptionLabel={item => {
        // console.log( '====>' , typeof item === "string" ? props.options.find(i => i.gender_name_short === item).gender_name_long : item.gender_name_long)
        return typeof item === "string"
          ? props.options.find(i => i.gender_name_short === item)
              .gender_name_long
          : item.gender_name_long;
      }}
      // getOptionLabel={item => typeof item === 'string' ? props.options.find(i => i.gender_name_short === item).gender_name_long : item.gender_name_long}
      getOptionSelected={(item, current) => {
        return item.gender_name_short === current;
      }}
      // defaultValue={'hi'}
      renderInput={props => (
        <TextField
          {...props}
          {...textFieldProps}
          helperText={helperText}
          error={error}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

const SimpleFormExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Simple Form Example</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      validateOnBlur={false}
      validateOnChange
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm, setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        resetForm();
        // setSubmitting(false);
      }}
    >
      {formik => (
        <Form>
          <Field
            name="gender"
            component={FormikAutocomplete}
            label="gender"
            options={gender}
            textFieldProps={{
              fullWidth: true,
              margin: "normal",
              variant: "outlined"
            }}
            // multiple
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

export default SimpleFormExample;
```

Comment: I had tried this but i get the following error when i select the option in the dropdown.

"Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "F"."

Comment: Your demo also returns the error in the console.  How to get rid of that error.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, in addition to the error in the log, the text field value is blank on selection.

Comment: updated the answer as well as the codesandbox demo (use the same link in the answer, refresh browser) ..... all the issues are resolved .... just a quick note , since for your usecase, you have to use onChange, `setFormValue` etc , you can also  don't use `Field` for `gender`, rather just directly use auto complete and do setFormValue upon onChange... if this `quick note` seems confusing just ignore it and just use the working code as per the answer... thx..